# PHP $_SERVER not working

Tags: php, ip, server

I have tried to write a script that takes the users IP address,but for
some reason the `$_SERVER` variable is not receiving any values,so I tested 
it if it's actually containing anything and the result was empty. 
It's the same story with `$_GET`,`$_POST`.Is there someone who had similar problem, because I saw a guy in Youtube making a script similar to mine 
and he didn't have this error.

```
$http_client_IP  =  $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];

   if ( empty($http_client_ip)){
       echo 'empty'; // and the result is empty 
   }



?>
```

Comment: Variables are **cAsE sEnSiTiVe**! (BTW:  There is no `HTTP_CLIENT_IP` index)

Answer (score 1):

```
$http_client_IP  =  $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];

   if ( empty($http_client_IP)){
       echo 'empty'; // and the result is empty 
   }
```

You have changed the variable name its case sensitive  change $http_client_ip to $http_client_IP.

Comment: 1. no explanation what and why you changed it!!